# Adobe Reader: send to printer command line

Tags: command-line, pdf, adobe-reader

Following the answer below:

[SO - Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/619203/6725364)

I was struggling to make that command, `AcroRd32.exe /t <filename> <printername> <drivername> <portname>`, work with the latest version of Adobe Reader DC. The problem was that the files were not sent to the printer (I tried multiple variations of the command).

I found a solution by installing an older version of Adobe Reader, v9. However, I would like to use the latest version of Adobe Reader.

**Isn't the print command working anymore in the new version of Adobe Reader or has the command changed?**

---

PS: Foxit Reader, RawFilePrinter, SumatraPDF, 2Printer are not suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
AcroRd32.exe /N /T <filename> <printername>
```

This worked for me as it was would previously work for an older version but when I upgraded to Adobe Reader DC it stopped working.

Comment: If works for me with Adobe Reader DC 2019.010